# Subset sum variation

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, subset-sum

Given an integer `n` and `s` sets of different sizes, but with positive ascending numbers from `0` to `s_i` as elements. Let a good sum be defined here as `a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_s = n`. Count how many sums are existent, when you take for every `a_i` an element from it's corresponding set `s_i`.

I tried to generate any possible way and omit those which are omittable, i.e. when you have for example `s=3`, `n=1` and you are given the sets `s_0={0,1}`, `s_1={0,1,2,3}`, `s_2={0,1,2}`, then you can omit the check for the sum `0 + 0 + a_3` since `a_3` won't be able to be large enough.
I've applied the dynamic programming solution for normal subset sum for each of those possible sequences, however, I get much larger results than I should and its very slow, too.

Are there any good algorithms which I can apply here?

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a slight variation on the classical subset sum solution, by using two dictionaries (arrays can also work, but dictionaries are nicer):

```
dp[i] = dictionary of sums we can obtain using the first i sets and their counts


dp[0, <elements in s[0]>] = 1
for i = 1 to s - 1:
  for each element x in dp[i - 1]:
    for each element k in s[i]:
      dp[i, x + k] += dp[i - 1, x]
```

Complexity will be quite large, but there's not much you can do to reduce it I think. It should work though.

You can get away with only keeping two dictionaries in memory, because you only need the current and the previous ones.

Python code:

```
def solve(s, n):

    dp = [dict()] * len(s)

    for k in s[0]:
        dp[0][k] = 1
    for i in range(1, len(s)):
        dp[i] = dict()
        for x in dp[i - 1]:
            for k in s[i]:
                if x + k in dp[i]:
                    dp[i][x + k] += dp[i - 1][x]
                else:
                    dp[i][x + k] = dp[i - 1][x]

    return dp[len(s) - 1][n]

print(solve([[0,1,2],[0,1,2]], 3)) # prints 2
print(solve([[0,1,2],[0,1,2,3,4],[0,1,2,3,4]], 5)) # prints 13
```

Comment: @user5379430 it's an array of `s` dictionaries. Each entry `(k, v)` in a dictionary means that you can make up some `k` in `v` ways.

Comment: @user5379430 in `dp[s - 1][n]`.

Comment: @user5379430 I posted a Python code that gives 2 for your example. If you post your code, we might be able to help you debug it.

Comment: So I seem to still have some misunderstanding issues for `dp`, as you explained it, it seems to be 1 dim, but you're using it as 2 dim.

Comment: @user5379430 it's 2d because each element of `dp` is a dictionary. So the dictionary adds the second dimension. Are you familiar with dictionaries? What language do you want to code this in?

Comment: Try `[[0,1,2],[0,1,2,3,4],[0,1,2,3,4]],5`, it should be 13, shouldn't it?

Comment: @user5379430 indeed, my algorithm returned 17. The problem was that by copying the previous dict and then performing the updates, you would also count solutions that don't use elements from **all** of the current `i` sets (for example, it would count `2+0+3` AND `2+3`). To fix it, don't copy the previous dictionary into the current one at the beginning. I updated the code, which now prints 13 for your example.